# How to properly separate this regex into two lines?

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex that checks if a string is an URL:

```
const regex = /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%!\-\/]))?/
```

I tried this:

```
const regex = '/(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?' + // eslint-disable-line
'(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%!\-\/]))?/' // eslint-disable-line
```

But the regex doesn't match anymore. Same for this one:

```
const regex = new RegExp(['/(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?', // eslint-disable-line
'(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%!\-\/]))?/'].join('')) // eslint-disable-line
```

What's the proper way of doing this?

**EDIT:**

Sample string: `http://vrcam-10065475.image.myqcloud.com/7a88620cb5ec7eb90164.jpg?imageView2/2/w/600/h/600/q/100/format/jpg`

Comment: Use `var regex = new RegExp(['(http|https)://(\\w+:?\\w*)?(\\S+)(:[0-9]+)?', // eslint-disable-line` and `'(/|/([\\w#!:.?+=&%!/-]))?'].join('')) // eslint-disable-line`. That is: double the backslashes in the constructor notation and remove regex delimiters. Hyphen moved to the end of the character class will always match a literal hyphen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try that:

```
var regex = RegExp(
  "(http|https)://(\\w+:{0,1}\\w*)?(\\S+)(:[0-9]+)?" +
  "(/|/([\\w#!:.?+=&%!-/]))?"
);
```

[Run the sample here](https://jsfiddle.net/9kw4L8q6/)

Comment: There is no need to escape a slash in the constructor notation, `\/` => `/`, and the hyphen turns out unescaped with a single backslash (`"[!\-\/]"` is equal to `/[!-\/]/` that creates a range).

Comment: The regex doesn't match.

Comment: @alex can you please provide some sample text that you want to match ?

Comment: can you try now ?

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked! Weird, why did the long version work and not the multiline one?

Comment: When you use RegExp you don't need to escape / .And also you don't need to put / at the start and at the end